# How to sort it in jpql?

Tags: sql, jpql

I want to sort it in the following order: eee, ddd, then other in alphabetical order.

```
input:
1: aaa
2: bbb
3: ccc
4: ddd
5: eee

output:
1: eee
2: ddd
3: aaa
4: bbb
5: ccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to get 'eee' and 'ddd' first, then sort the rest alphabetically:

```
ORDER BY case when col = 'eee' then 1
              when col = 'ddd' then 2
              else 3
         end,
         col
```